# Javascript Error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to resolve the issue .I cant load this script http://orangeplacehotel.com/superbudget/ems-policy. Is there anything wrong with this code?? I tried putting alert and it works properly but still i cant see the plug-in loaded on the site.. Please help .. Thanks,

```js
$(function() {
    $('#nanoGallery1').nanoGallery({
        kind:'flickr',
        userID:'129251189@N05',
        touchAutoOpenDelay: -1,
        breadcrumbAutoHideTopLevel: true,
        maxWidth: 948,
        imageTransition : 'slide',
        thumbnailWidth: 200,
        thumbnailHeight: 126,
        thumbnailHoverEffect: 'scaleLabelOverImage,borderDarker',
        i18n: {
            thumbnailImageDescription: 'view photo',
            thumbnailAlbumDescription: 'open album'
        },
        thumbnailLabel: {
            display: true,
            position: 'overImageOnMiddle',
            hideIcons: true, align: 'center'
        },
        thumbnailLazyLoad: true 
    });
});
alert("test");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: (The snipped) It says `nanoGallery` is not a function, which isn't surprising. Since you provide a snippet I expected a self-contained example?

Comment: Works for me, gallery loads just fine.

Comment: Indeed gallery is loading, but some data is missing: http://prntscr.com/5phkm9

Comment: Can you please help me with this? I'm confused. I tried this code mostly on my sites and it works properly. http://theblackboardbychefmichel.com/ems-policy

Comment: I also tried using jquery no-conflict but it doesnt work.

Comment: briosheje what data is missing? have i missed something?

Answer (score 1):

error is "NanoGallery is not a function"
I think you should check your plugin (in what nanoGaller() is defined) is included in page or not before running your code

Below is the code working fine
Its not a solution but might give you some idea

First include the jquery library then

```
$.prototype.nanoGallery = function(){
    console.log(arguments);
}

$(function() {
    $('#nanoGallery1').nanoGallery({
        kind:'flickr',
        userID:'129251189@N05',
        touchAutoOpenDelay: -1,
        breadcrumbAutoHideTopLevel: true,
        maxWidth: 948,
        imageTransition : 'slide',
        thumbnailWidth: 200,
        thumbnailHeight: 126,
        thumbnailHoverEffect: 'scaleLabelOverImage,borderDarker',
        i18n: {
            thumbnailImageDescription: 'view photo',
            thumbnailAlbumDescription: 'open album'
        },
        thumbnailLabel: {
            display: true,
            position: 'overImageOnMiddle',
            hideIcons: true, align: 'center'
        },
        thumbnailLazyLoad: true 
    });

});

alert("test");
```

Comment: Thanks works great! :) What i did is include first Jquery Library and put it into No-Conflict Mode then use the more concise syntax for the DOM ready function..

Comment: Now i got this working on two of subdomains http://orangeplacehotel.com/boutique/ems-policy and http://orangeplacehotel.com/superbudget/ems-policy ..